# Incrementing a UILabel in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So essentially I want the UILabel to increment every time a button is clicked. I currently have something like this:

```
- (IBAction) incrementCount {
    [buttonCounter = buttonCounter++]; // Increment by 1.
}
```

I declare button counter to be an int in the header file. Is that the right way of doing it? Furthemore, upon click, i'd like a time stamp printed as well. Is there a built-in function for fetching a time stamp? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
- (IBAction) incrementCount {
    buttonCounter++;
    yourUILabel.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", buttonCounter];
}
```

You can get a current date and time using 
    [NSDate date]
To get timestamp, use 
    [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;

Comment: Is it appropriate for me to define buttonCounter in my header file or should I just define it in my incrementCount method?

Comment: You need it to be persisent - if you define it in method, its value will be lost after the method execution ends. So it should be declared in header file.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense. Lastly, how would I declare its value? I tried doing it in the header method, but i'm assuming that isn't allowed. Do I simply make a setter method?

-(void) setValue {
buttonCounter = 0;
}

Comment: @property can solve all getter and setter problems. If you want to initialize values, use either init methods (in all objects) or viewDidLoad method in UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
[buttonCounter = buttonCounter++];
```

is equivalent to

```
[buttonCounter = buttonCounter+1];
[buttonCounter = buttonCounter];
```

Therefore you can change your code to

```
buttonCounter++;
```

For the timestamp you could use `[NSDate date];` and a `NSDateFormatter` for the display.